# How to select all the authors from database with the number of books assigned to them?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I've the following DB structure:

```
Authors(id,name);
Books(id,title,authorId);
```

I want to select all fields from authors and the number of books they are assigned to. I've managed to get the result, but **only for the authors that are assigned to at least one book**, which is not what I want. I tried with the following query:

```
SELECT books.*,authors.* 
FROM authors 
FULL OUTER JOIN books 
  ON authors.id = books.authorId;
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Your query is not turning a count, so it doesn't seem related to your comment in bold.

Comment: @GordonLinoff 'at least one' doesn't require a count

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you want a `left join` and aggregation:

```
select a.id, a.name, count(*)
from authors a
left join books b on b.authorId = a.id
group by a.id, a.name
```

Answer (score 0):

`outer join` will bring back authors without books. Instead use `inner join` and your results will only bring back authors with at least 1 book.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT a.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM books b
        WHERE a.id = b.authorId
       ) as num_books
FROM authors;
```

This allows you to use `SELECT a.*` from `authors`.  If you put a `GROUP BY` in the outer query, you either need to list all the columns separately or be using a database that allows you to aggregate by a primary key, while selecting other columns (this is standard functionality but most databases do not support it).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you need LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY, but details is not clear enough from the task description. Let's try a kind of

```sql
SELECT b.*, ab.count
FROM authors AS a 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT authorId, COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM books 
  GROUP BY authorId
) AS ab ON a.id = ab.authorId;
```

also, if you don't want to get NULL for some authors, you can apply such expression:

```
IFNULL(ab.count, 0) AS count
```